# Mapping and choosing from an array of arrays(which is just a pair of elements). Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

`[["A", 0], ["B", 0], ["b", 0], ["F", 1], ["G", 2], ["g", 3], ["C", 0]]`

and I want to choose from the pair if it's 0 or not and create a new array that results into this

`["A","B","b",1,2,3,"C"]`

I tried using

```
arr.each do |a| 
  if a.last == 0
    a.first
  else
    a.last
  end
end
```

but it returns the original array.

Answer (score 1):

You are really close. Just use `map` instead of `each`. `each` just loops through the `Enumerable` it is called on and returns the original object. `map` also loops through the `Enumerable` but returns an `Array` of result values of those iterations.

To pass a different value as a result value of an iteration block than a return value of its last command use `next`. Calling `next value` will stop processing the current loop with `value` as its result.

Your working code is:

```rb
arr = [["A", 0], ["B", 0], ["b", 0], ["F", 1], ["G", 2], ["g", 3], ["C", 0]]
new_arr = arr.map do |a| 
  if a.last == 0
    a.first
  else
    a.last
  end
end
#=>  ["A", "B", "b", 1, 2, 3, "C"]
```

A code example using `next`

```rb
arr = [["A", 0], ["B", 0], ["b", 0], ["F", 1], ["G", 2], ["g", 3], ["C", 0]]
new_arr = arr.map do |a| 
  next a.first if a.last == 0
  a.last
end
#=>  ["A", "B", "b", 1, 2, 3, "C"]
```

Comment: *"if you want to return a value out of loop you call `next`, not `return`"* This statement is very confusing because `next` does not return it just skips the remainder of the block (with an optional argument to be used as the result of the iteration). You can `break` to stop iterating (with an optional argument to be used as the result of the block).

Comment: @engineersmnky "result of an iteration" is the correct term, the word return did not feel right but I could not get out of a functional language mindset. I have edited the answer and used the correct term.

Answer (score 0):

instead of #each or even map you could also use #each_with_object, you could pass in any object of your choice but sounds like you want an array here is an example

```
new_array = input.each_with_object([]) do |a, arr|
  # the second value `arr` passed to the block is the []
  arr << if a.last.zero?
   a.first
  else
    a.last
  end
end
#=>  ["A", "B", "b", 1, 2, 3, "C"]
```